# I installed my cedar fence 2 months ago. Can I stain it next year?

Tags: fence, stain

This is a knotty cedar board fence. I did not have enough time to stain it this year. On top of that I plan to redo my deck next year in April-May. I would  like to give the same stain.

**Is it too late to stain the fence next year? What problems could I have?** Am I going to see a sensible difference between the two, fence and deck? They are not exactly next to each other, the fence is at the front, the deck is on the side, you can see the fence from the deck but not the other way around, when you look at the house from the street you see the fence but you can not see the deck (hidden behind the garage)

Comment: Staining cedar is entirely optional and cosmetic. I can't see any reason you couldn't wait until next year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you can stain it whenever. It will catch up to the other areas that were stained already. Usually, you want Cedar to season for at least 6-months.